# BlackBerry App not support Force Landscape mode after porting from Android

Tags: android, android-layout, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I have Android app which is work only in Landscape mode. but when I port it in Blackberry 10 using Eclipse Android run-time beta 2.0. this app open in portrait mode not open in landscape mode.

Is Blackberry not support Android Orientation?

How to check orientation in Blackberry Simulator 10?

Comment: I have ported android app to BB10 in the past, and force orientation worked. Which way are you force-rotating? (manifest, in code...)

Comment: Hi,  i am using in manifest : android:screenOrientation="landscape"
and  in java file for programmatically change orientation :  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: is there any problem?

Comment: I only used `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` in manifest and it worked. Maybe it doesn't rotate in simulator, I always used a device to test.

Comment: just wait i will put this. and check. thanks for help.

Comment: hey can you help me? in my simulator  not work in landscape mode.

Comment: i will give you Bar file can you check in your device?

Comment: I can try. Make sure apk is signed

Comment: I think you can close this, as rotation does work, just not on simulator.